# Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(n)}{n+1} \times \arcsin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ converge or diverge? and why?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

Looking at this sum:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(n)}{n+1} \times \arcsin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) $$

I am supposed to determine weather this one diverges or conveges.
At first I thought about doing the following comparison test:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(n)}{n+1} \times \arcsin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) > \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+1} $$

Then, using anotheer comparison test with this sum $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} $I determined that my original sum diverges.

My problem is with the $ \arcsin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) $. I know that if it was a "regular" $\arcsin$ function, it will have a final result at infinity, but this case looks a bit different, since the whole expression goes to $0$. Does it change my answer? what should I do with that?

Thanks

Comment: $\arcsin \left( \frac{1}{n} \right) \approx \frac{1}{n}$ as $n\to\infty$

Comment: So, does it mean that my sum shoulde converge?

Comment: Yes, it should. One can show fairly quickly by means of a graph that $\arcsin x \le \frac{\pi x}{2}$ for $x \ge 0$, and then you just need to show that this sequence you use as an upper bound also has convergent sum.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\arcsin (\frac{1}{n})\sim_{+\infty} \frac{1}{n}$
Therefore using the [Cauchy condensation test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) 
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(n)}{n+1} \times \arcsin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)= 
 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^n \frac{n\ln(2)}{2^n+1} \times \arcsin\left(\frac{1}{2^n}\right) $$ but for $n\to +\infty$ the series becomes$$\frac {n\ln 2}{2^n}$$ and using [the root test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test)$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty} \left (\frac {n\ln 2}{2^n}\right )^{\frac{1}{n}}= \frac {1}{2}<1$$ therefore the series converges.